# Has there been a (sustained) downward trend in the amount of EU Commission's press releases in the past decade?

Tags: european-union, public-relations

Wikipedia seems to [suggest so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Commission#Press)

> Where there are multiple departments involved a press release can also be a source of competition between areas of the Commission and Commissioners themselves. This also leads to an unusually high number of press releases, 1907 for 2006, and is seen as a unique product of the EU's political set-up.[76] The number of Commission press releases shows a decreasing trend. 1768 press releases were published in 2010 and 1589 in 2011.[79]

But it only has data for 3 years, and ends in 2011. Has the trend continued? And if there is a trend, have there been any published analyses/hypotheses as to the purported reason for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same source the writer(s) of the Wikipedia article did ([EU Commission Press Release Database](http://europa.eu/rapid/search.htm)) you'll notice that it wasn't only the Press Releases, all documents in general show a decreasing trend particularly from 2013 forward:

[image: EU Press Releases per year 1997-2017]

The source for your quoted text conclusion is [Maria Lindholm](https://benjamins.com/catalog/prag.18.1.03lin/fulltext/prag.18.1.03lin.pdf) and its study is from 2008, too old to answer the sharp decrease of 2013. Probably a much better explanation is some of the cuts that were made during the recession, for example by closing [Presseurop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presseurop).